# Help calculating opposing dice pool in AnyDice

Tags: dice, statistics, anydice

I need to calculate the probability of **A winning against B**.
Both A and B throw 1-15 d6s, the one with more successful dice (SD) wins.

There are actually 5 possibles outcomes:

- `CF: A's SD < B's SD -3`
- `F:  A's SD < B's SD`
- `DR: A's SD = B's SD`
- `S:  A's SD > B's SD`
- `CF: A's SD > B's SD +3`

A die can give 4 different outcomes:

- `Roll 1:   -1 SD`
- `Roll 2-3:  0 SD`
- `Roll 4-5: +1 SD`
- `Roll 6:   +2 SD`

I want to see the probability of A outcomes in different situations, with the number of dice for A and B going from 1 to 15.

I've done something in `AnyDice`, but looking further into the documentation I think I completely messed up:

```
function: singledice DICE:n{
 if DICE = 1 {result : -1 }
 if DICE = 2 {result : 0 }
 if DICE = 3 {result : 0 }
 if DICE = 4 {result : 1 }
 if DICE = 5 {result : 1 }
 if DICE = 6 {result : 2 }
}

function: throw A dices{
 X: 0
 loop N over{1..A}{
   X : X + [singledice d6]
 }
 result: X
}

function: players K and L{
 CF:0
 F:0
 DR:0
 S:0
 CS:0
 loop G over{1..K}{
   loop H over{1..L}{
     C:[throw G dices]-[throw H dices]
     if C < -3 {CF:CF+1}else
     if C < -1 {F:F+1} else
     if C = 0 {DR:DR+1}else
     if C = 1 {S:S+1}else
     if C = 2 {S:S+1}else
     if C > 2 {CS:CS+1}
     }
}
result: {CF, F, DR, S, CS}
}

loop M over{1..15}{
  loop U over{1..15}{
    output [players M and U] named "[M] vs [U]"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered by Jasper Flick, the creator of AnyDice: http://anydice.com/program/6268

Here is the code

```
function: check A:n vs B:n {
 if A < B - 3 { result: -2 } \ CF \
 if A < B { result: -1 } \ F \
 if A > B + 3 { result: 2 } \ CS \
 if A > B { result: 1 } \ S \
 result: 0 \ DR \
}

SD: d{-1, 0:2, 1:2, 2}

loop A over {1..15} {
 A_POOL: AdSD
 loop B over {1..15} {
  output [check A_POOL vs BdSD] named "[A] vs [B]"
 }
}
```

I hope I can leave this here, there are some tricks that may be useful for other users (like the die with different odds).